# Ignore entire folder using du -I

Tags: command-line, unix

I tried to ignore an entire subfolder of the current folder when running `du`:

`du -I=./subfolder -sh`

This, however, gives me the grand total size of the current folder as if the `-I` never worked. I read from manpage that:

> -I mask
>            Ignore files and folders matching the specified mask.

So it's supposed to work with folders.
But all the examples that I found online specify simple globs like `-I="*.txt"`.

Is it that the folder must take on a specific form instead of a plain relative path?

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem myself:

The single-dash option `-I` does not accept `=`. The convention is that double-dash options `--` require `=`.

I fixed by using `-I ./subfolder` instead.